# Questions related to "System Type" and installation of 64 bit OS

Tags: windows-7

I want to upgrade my existing 32 bit Windows 7 Enterprise operating system to 64 bit. My first question:

- Would I need 64 bit processor or I can get a 64 bit OS on a 32 bit processor? I think I will need 64 bit processor but I will come to it on why I get all this confusion.
- Which is right to say - "I need 64 bit processor" or "I need 64 bit hardware architecture"?

  - If "I need 64 bit hardware architecture" is correct way to say it then apart from processor what all things would be 64 bit, I guess complete motherboard needs to be 64 bit complaint, right?

Now, this whole confusion came because I checked the "System Type" and it showed `X86-based PC` (*please see my system screen shot in the end*), so my understanding was that my system is a 32 bit processor/hardware, but I went to OS installation guy then he went to the BIOS settings (which comes by continuously pressing F11 while booting system) and showed me that it is 64 bit processor. So, my questions are:

- What does "System Type" tells about, my understanding was that it tell about processor/hardware type?

  - If my understanding is correct then why it happened that when OS installation guy went to the BIOS settings then he could show me processor as 64 bit?

**Please provide answers for my "each" question.**

*My System Summary screen shot:*

[image]

---

**EDIT**

So, for installing a 64 bit OS I would just need a 64 bit processor OR I would need a 64 bit motherboard? If 64 bit motherboard then what all things need to be 64 bit, I mean address bus, but is it a hardware or a logical entity?

*I know my concepts are quite broken because I am not a computer science graduate, so I am trying to fill the gap and that's where I need help from you guys. When I say "64 bit motherboard" I mean on motherboard where I will have 64 bit processor, and then what else? So, basically if I have a 64 bit processor then its sufficient or I would need more?*

Answer (score 1):

> Can get a 64 bit OS on a 32 bit processor?

- **All** 32-bit processor are x86 processors
- **All** 64-bit processor is a x86 processor, that supports the 64-bit extension, to the x86 archectecture.
- The [Intel® Core™ i5-4310U Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/80343/Intel-Core-i5-4310U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_00-GHz), supports Intel's version of this extension, called **Intel 64**.

> Which is right to say - "I need 64 bit processor" or "I need 64 bit
>   hardware architecture"?

Honestly, neither are correct, both fail to recgonize that all 64-bit processors are x86 processors.  *You also already have hardware, that supports, the 64-bit extension.*

> Now, this whole confusion came because I checked the "System Type" and
>   it showed X86-based PC, so my understanding was that my system is a 32
>   bit processor/hardware, but I went to OS installation guy then he went
>   to the BIOS settings and showed me that it is 64 bit processor.

You have to fall back to the fact, that all 64-bit processors are x86 processors, this means that all 64-bit processors support 32-bit software.  Your system just happens to have a 32-bit operating system installed.  Windows will identify itself, as x86 or x64, depending if it's a 32-bit or 64-bit installation.

> What does "System Type" tells about, my understanding was that it tell
>   about processor/hardware type?

*System Type*, indicates the bitness of the operating system, that is about it.

> If my understanding is correct then why it happened that when OS
>   installation guy went to the BIOS settings then he could show me
>   processor as 64 bit?

Your understanding is actually incorrect, so the "os installation guy", simply showed you that the processor you have supports the 64-bit extension.

> So, for installing a 64 bit OS I would just need a 64 bit processor OR
>   I would need a 64 bit motherboard?

There is no such thing as a 64-bit motherboard.

> When I say "64 bit motherboard" I mean on motherboard where I will
>   have 64 bit processor, and then what else?

You should stop calling it that, because when you talk to somebody who does understand, they won't understand what you are talking about.

> So, basically if I have a 64 bit processor then its sufficient or I
>   would need more?

The hardware you currently have supports 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: If your comment isn't how I can improve my answer, take your discussion, to the chatroom please.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52987/discussion-on-answer-by-ramhound-questions-related-to-system-type-and-installa).